# Notation for CDF of the binomial distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, notation

The CDF for $X \sim \operatorname{Bin}(n,p)$ is $I_{1-p}(n-k,1+k)$. What does the $I$ mean?

Comment: It's the first symbol of an incomplete beta function. See (e.g.) http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17

Comment: [Closely related, but not (in my opinion) a duplicate](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/66752/22228)

Answer (score 7):

As Nick Cox pointed out, this is the incomplete beta function. Of course, you might naturally wonder how this function has come to appear in the CDF of the (discrete) binomial distribution. The reason for this is the following identity, for which you might want to keep an eye out in the future.

$$ \int_{0}^p \frac{n!}{\left(k-1\right)! \left(n-k\right)!} z^{k-1} \left(1-z\right)^{n-k} dz = \sum_{w=k} ^n \binom{n}{w} p ^w \left(1-p \right)^{n-w} $$

You can verify this by differentiating both sides w.r.t $p$. If you modify this a little bit, you will get exactly the result you posted. Note finally that this relationship can also be given a probabilistic interpretation in terms of probabilities of success.

Comment: (+1) "Note finally that this relationship can also be given a probabilistic interpretation in terms of probabilities of success." I think it's worth expanding on this a little

Comment: +1 However, generally speaking, having the same derivative won't of itself make two functions equal.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes indeed, the functions may still differ by a constant. Integration by parts should work as well, although I have not tried it myself.

Comment: @Silverfish I don't have the time right now to explain this well, but you can think in terms of order statistics of the uniform distribution, which have the beta distribution as you know. Then both the LHS and the RHS describe the same event.